# TaskCompletionSource with native async callback not working in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I have got a C library which does stuff asynchronously and returns the result in the provided callback (a function ptr). Say this is one of the functions:

**C code:**

```
void c_foo(void(*cb)(char*)) {
  // spawn a thread
  // sleep in the new-thread for sometime
  // invoke the callback: cb(some_null_terminated_string)
  // exit the thread
}
```

I also created a similar looking `C#` code just to test things:

**C# code:**

```
public void TestManaged(Action<string> abcd) {
  var thread = new Thread(
    () => {
      Thread.Sleep(5000);
      abcd("Done");
    });
  thread.Start();
}
```

As you can see, it returns the control to the caller immediately, while the callback is called sometime later in a thread spawned by it.

I'm trying to use this from `C#` but facing problems. The objects which I think should not have been destroyed are getting destroyed. Here is a sample code:

```
public class Checker {
  public string ABCD = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

  ~Checker() {
     Debug.WriteLine("DESTROYING!!!!");
  }
}

public Task<string> Foo() {
  return Task.Run(
    () => {
      var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
      var a = new Checker(); // --- (0)
      Debug.WriteLine("T-ID: Main - " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

      // Run Either: ---------- (1)
      // This DOES NOT work, `a` gets destroyed before the callback is invoked
      TestNative(
        s => {
          Debug.WriteLine("T-ID: CB - " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
          Debug.WriteLine(a.ABCD);
          tcs.SetResult(s);
        });

      // OR:  ------------------ (2)
      // This Works
      TestManaged((s) =>
      {
        Debug.WriteLine("T-ID: CB - " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Debug.WriteLine(a.ABCD);
        tcs.SetResult(s);
      });

      return tcs.Task;
    });
}
```

The glue for the native `C` definitions:

```
public delegate void TestCb(string s);
[DllImport("mydll", EntryPoint = "c_foo")]
public static extern void TestNative(TestCb cb);
```

And finally, I'm just invoking the setup as:

```
Debug.WriteLine("Result: " + await Foo());
```

In the code above I either comment out `(1)` and use `(2)` or do it the other way, so that only one of them executes for a particular run. The problem is that I see object `a` which is created at the point marked `(0)`, gets destroyed if the `C` code is called via `(1)` but remains preserved when `C#` code is called via `(2)` although both of them spawn a thread and invoke the passed callback only after sometime asynchronously. This obviously causes `(1)` to crash.

Also if it's helpful - if the `C` code didn't spawn a thread but invoked the given callback in the caller's (`C#`'s) thread, things are fine even with `(1)` - the surrounding context is not destroyed.

Why is this happening and what is the way to work with such `C` libraries (which invoke callbacks from their own spawned threads).

Comment: Dinna know, but workaround https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.keepalive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @Will well it is alive until `return tcs.Task;` anyway - it's destroyed only after returning the task. So where would you even put it. Besides, this is a simplified example to showcase the problem. I don't know how viable that solution would be in a full blown production code involving many variables etc.

Comment: I'd tell the GC I don't want it collected on creation (or anytime prior to `return` then tell the GC it's clear to collect after `tcs.SetResult`... But, yes, adapting that to actual production code can be tricky. It's similar to managing object lifespans across appdomains, although that's a bit more clear using the ILease and ISponsor interfaces.  Again, it's a workaround, not an explanation why the GC isn't recognizing you *should* have a reference (via the closure--I wonder what the closure's IL looks like, is it different than the managed version's?) or why you don't.

Comment: Without a good [mcve] reliably reproducing the problem, it's impossible to provide a good answer. That said, IMHO you are lucky the callback is executed at all, never mind whether `a` is collected or not. You're doing nothing in the C# code to retain any of the objects involved during the async operation, including the object `a` _and_ the `TestCb` delegates you pass to `TestNative()`. The delegates in particular are a big problem because often they are collected and the call from native code will just be to an invalid address. Fix your question if you want specific, genuine help.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: When you say `a` and delegates are not retained, how are they retained in `(2)` for the call to the managed function `TestManaged` which also returns control back immediately ? Maybe this is the part i'm getting wrong - while `(2)` works `(1)` doesn't - so is there something specific about `(1)` that makes GC collect everything away ?

Comment: `TestManaged()` is, duh, entirely managed. This means that all references are visible to the runtime. In particular, the delegate remains reachable via capturing in `TestManaged()`'s thread, that delegate references the compiler-generated capturing class for `a`, and `a` remains reachable via that class. But in the `TestNative()` class, there's no managed thread that provides the context for the GC to find the passed delegate still reachable; with the delegate found to be unreachable, it and all objects chained from it can be collected.

Comment: This is a classic limitation of any scenario where unmanaged code is involved. Managed code is, by definition, entirely managed by the runtime. You never need to worry about how or why references remain reachable and valid; that's the whole point of managed code. It always ensures that they will, as an inherent part of its design. But when native/unmanaged code gets involved, the runtime doesn't always have complete knowledge of object lifetimes and reachability and may GC things before you're done with them. It's up to _you_ to make sure that doesn't happen.

Comment: @PeterDuniho ah that explains it - i am not a c# coder, just mocking a c# API with very limited knowledge of it to see how it's going to interact with my C lib. Can you pls tell me a way to instruct C# to not garbage collect the anonymous delegate passed to `TestNative` ? That way i think `a` which is captured by that anonymous delegate will also be kept alive ? (Feel free to put it as an answer if you want - you are basically answering the question in the post anyway).

Comment: I can't tell you specifically how to do it in your example, because you haven't provided a [mcve] showing what your entire scenario looks like. However, the basic idea will be to store the delegate reference in a variable instead of passing it directly to `TestNative()`. Then pass that variable's value to the method and make sure the variable itself remains reachable at least until the callback is executed (a static field would trivially remain reachable, but may not be appropriate if you have multiple such calls executing concurrently).

Comment: There is also `GC.KeepAlive()`, which would likely work if you'd refactor your `Foo()` method and the `Task.Run()` anonymous method to use `await`, but again...without a good [mcve] showing all the details, I can't see a way to write a good answer explaining that in your particular scenario. Without being able to reproduce the problem, and then verify that the problem has been fixed, I can't in good conscience post code purporting to fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no automatic notion in .NET of native methods hanging on to managed objects.  You must inform the runtime of such cases.

Reference: [GCHandle Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle(v=vs.110).aspx)

In your case, this should do it:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

      var callbackHandle = default(GCHandle);
      Action<string> nativeCallback = s => {
        try {
          Debug.WriteLine("T-ID: CB - " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
          Debug.WriteLine(a.ABCD);
          tcs.SetResult(s);
        }
        finally {
          if (callbackHandle.IsAllocated) {
            callbackHandle.Free();
          }
        }
      };
      callbackHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(nativeCallback);
      TestNative(nativeCallback);
```

You must do this on the callback and not only on `a`, since the callback itself would be subject to garbage collection after `TestNative` returns.  In this case, it's enough to use a `GCHandle` on the callback since the callback captures `a` and if the callback is reachable, `a` is reachable.

Comment: Ah brilliant, will try this. In the meantime what i did was put a global list of `object` in which i add all callbacks i give to C, and from inside the callback remove itself from that list as the last thing thus tell GC it's ok to GC it now. I learned objects are address compared so i don't need explicit comparison specification.

Comment: Your approach works just as fine, perhaps a bit less performant depending on how often you pass such callbacks, and is probably easier to trace and debug future related issues.  Make sure the global list is accessed with proper synchronization.